# Spring AOP Exception

Tags: java, spring, aop

In my spring web project, AOP Event Trace give some excepting info like this:

```
9:42:56 Exception from reflection 'Aspect definition
  [\xxx\webapp\WEB-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml:33] advise type [after] advise
  [com.xxx.PrivilegeAspect.aroundDoPrivilege(org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint)]'
  while processing bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
  #leap.web#xxx/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/spring-mvc.xml#26 (26)
  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]'
  key codes in `spring-mvc.xml`:
```

```xml
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>

<!-- component scan -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx" use-default-filters="false">
<context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>

<!-- json convert -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" />
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
<beans:property name="messageConverters">
    <beans:list>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
    </beans:list>
</beans:property>
```

key codes in `applicationContext.xml`:

```xml
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
<beans:import resource="applicationContext-tx.xml" />

<!-- component scan -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx" use-default-filters="false">
<context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
<context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
<context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Component" />
```

key codes in aspect class :

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class PrivilegeAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.xxx.controller.*.*(..))")
    public void aspect(){}

    @Around("aspect()")
    public Object aroundDoPrivilege(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    }
}
```

Now, aspect code is not work. I don't know why get these exception infos which I think is the root cause. thanks

Comment: Try adding try-catch and logging exception.

Comment: If that really is your aspect it breaks proper method invocation... Judging from the logging the code shown isn't the code used (the logging is mentioning `after` as advice type not `around`. But nonetheless the code still breaks proper execution.

Comment: You are right. I change @Around to @Before，log shows '... advise type [before] advise ...'。So I think the log info maybe right, but I don't know what happened?